# PHP 5.1.6 on Ubuntu

Tags: php, downgrade

I want to install PHP 5.1.6 on Ubuntu in order to work on legacy PHP application. How can I install PHP 5.1.6 on Ubuntu. I have tried to install 11.10 and followed many online resources to get it working but all in vain. Kindly help in this regard.

Comment: Go through this [link](https://gist.github.com/gmodarelli/5887778) it will help you. Follow the instruction carefully and installed according to your php version.

Comment: @AbdulKadir: I tried but compiling php 5.1.6 is not an option. It gives error during step of compile.

Comment: Send me the error.

Comment: last few lines are as follow

/opt/phpfarm/src/php-5.1.6/ext/dom/documenttype.c:219:65: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
    strintsubset = xmlStrndup(buff->buffer->content, buff->buffer->use);
                                                                 ^
make: *** [ext/dom/documenttype.lo] Error 1
make failed.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @AinTohvri: No! A temporary solution was to install code based on php 5.3 as PHP 5.1.6 ran fine.

Comment: For your information, I've produced a working Docker instance of 5.1.3 https://github.com/ain/docker-httpd

Answer (score 1):

Use Docker. I've produced a `5.1.3` version of PHP running on Apache. See (and contribute!) at https://github.com/ain/docker-httpd